# What pieces are needed to test a Spring Security Filter in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, servlet-filters

So I'm trying to test my security filters, and I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Some part of this code worked in the past, I'm splitting my project up into several libraries (and migrating from maven to gradle), so it's likely I've left either a dependency or some library off the class path. Let's start with the test

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@RunWith( SpringRunner.class )
public class AuthenticationTest extends AbstractSecurityTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
    @Autowired
    private Gson gson;
    @SpyBean
    private JsonAuthenticationFilter filter;

    @Test
    public void validLogin() throws Exception {
        log.debug( "posting password" );
        String json = gson.toJson( new PasswordCredential( name, pass ) );
        this.mvc.perform(
            post( JsonAuthenticationFilter.AUTH_PASS )
                .contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
                .content( json ) )
            .andExpect( status().is2xxSuccessful() )
            .andExpect( cookie().exists( "SESSION" ) );

        verify( filter, times( 1 ) )
            .doFilter( any( ServletRequest.class ), any( ServletResponse.class ), any( FilterChain.class ) );
    }

    @Test
    public void invalidLogin() throws Exception {
        String json = gson.toJson( new PasswordCredential( "xenoterracide@gmail.com", "password" ) );
        this.mvc.perform(
            post( JsonAuthenticationFilter.AUTH_PASS )
                .contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
                .accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
                .content( json ) )
            .andExpect( status().is4xxClientError() )
            .andExpect( status().isUnauthorized() );

        verify( filter, times( 1 ) )
            .doFilter( any( ServletRequest.class ), any( ServletResponse.class ), any( FilterChain.class ) );
    }

    @Test
    public void unsupportedMediaType() throws Exception {
        this.mvc.perform(
            post( JsonAuthenticationFilter.AUTH_PASS )
                .param( "pass", "password" )
                .param( "user", "xenoterracide@gmail.com" ) )
            .andExpect( status().is4xxClientError() );

        verify( filter, times( 1 ) )
            .doFilter( any( ServletRequest.class ), any( ServletResponse.class ), any( FilterChain.class ) );
    }
}
```

my assumption is that `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` by default should be including filters.

this is my authentication filter

```
@Component
class JsonAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    static final String AUTH_PASS = Routes.PUBLIC + "/authentication/password";

    private static final RequestMatcher MATCHER = new AndRequestMatcher( Arrays.asList(
        new AntPathRequestMatcher( AUTH_PASS, HttpMethod.POST.name() ),
        new MediaTypeRequestMatcher( new ContentTypeContentNegotiationStrategy(),
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 )
    ) );

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final Validator validator;

    protected JsonAuthenticationFilter( ObjectMapper objectMapper, Validator validator ) {
        super( MATCHER );
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
        throws AuthenticationException, IOException {

        PasswordCredential credentials = objectMapper.readValue( request.getReader(), PasswordCredential.class );

        try {
            DataBinder dataBinder = new DataBinder( credentials );
            dataBinder.setBindingErrorProcessor( new DefaultBindingErrorProcessor() );
            dataBinder.setValidator( validator );
            dataBinder.validate();
            dataBinder.close();
        }
        catch ( BindException e ) {
            throw new BadRequestException( "field errors", e );
        }

        AbstractAuthenticationToken authRequest = credentials.toAuthenticationToken();

        setDetails( request, authRequest );

        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate( authRequest );
    }

    private void setDetails( HttpServletRequest request, AbstractAuthenticationToken authRequest ) {
        authRequest.setDetails( authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails( request ) );
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired( required = false )
    public void setRememberMeServices( RememberMeServices rememberMeServices ) {
        super.setRememberMeServices( rememberMeServices );
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setAuthenticationManager( AuthenticationManager authenticationManager ) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager( authenticationManager );
    }
}
```

I know it's being `@Autowired`, and setting the `AuthenticationManager`, but the inherited `doFilter` is not being called.

```
plugins {
    `java-library`
    `maven-publish`
    `checkstyle`
    `idea`
    id("com.github.spotbugs").version("1.6.0")
    id("net.ltgt.errorprone").version("0.0.13")
    id("io.spring.dependency-management").version("1.0.4.RELEASE")
}

repositories {
    maven(System.getenv("JAR_REPOSITORY_URI"))
    jcenter()
}

group = "com.xenoterracide.rpf"
version = "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
description = "Security DTOs"

configurations.all({
    resolutionStrategy({
        cacheChangingModulesFor(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    })
})
dependencyManagement {
    resolutionStrategy({
        cacheChangingModulesFor(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    })
    imports {
        mavenBom("com.xenoterracide:bom:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT")
    }
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    errorprone("com.google.guava:guava:latest.release")
    errorprone("com.google.errorprone:error_prone_core:latest.release")

    compileOnly("com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305")
    compileOnly("com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:latest.release")

    implementation("javax.validation:validation-api")
    implementation("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-core")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-context")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-tx")
    implementation("org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons")
    implementation("org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-core")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web")


    implementation("com.xenoterracide.rpf:constants:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT")
    implementation("com.xenoterracide.rpf:sec-dtos:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT")
    implementation("com.xenoterracide.rpf:sec:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT")

    testRuntimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")

    testImplementation("junit:junit")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core")
    testImplementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3")
    testImplementation("com.google.code.gson:gson")
    testImplementation("org.assertj:assertj-core")
    testImplementation("org.springframework:spring-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure")

}
```

*update* adding requested class

```
class ContentTypeContentNegotiationStrategy implements ContentNegotiationStrategy {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @throws HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException if the 'Content-Type' header cannot be parsed
     */
    @Override
    public List<MediaType> resolveMediaTypes( NativeWebRequest request )
        throws HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException {

        String[] headerValueArray = request.getHeaderValues( HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE );
        if ( headerValueArray == null ) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        List<String> headerValues = Arrays.asList( headerValueArray );
        try {
            List<MediaType> mediaTypes = MediaType.parseMediaTypes( headerValues );
            MediaType.sortBySpecificityAndQuality( mediaTypes );
            return mediaTypes;
        }
        catch ( InvalidMediaTypeException ex ) {
            throw new HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException(
                "Could not parse 'Accept' header " + headerValues + ": " + ex.getMessage() );
        }
    }
}
```

and the output of a test failure

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /v0/public/authentication/password
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = Full authentication is required to access this resource
          Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY], Strict-Transport-Security=[max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains], WWW-Authenticate=[Basic realm="Spring"]}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /v0/public/authentication/password
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], Accept=[application/json]}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = Full authentication is required to access this resource
          Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY], Strict-Transport-Security=[max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains], WWW-Authenticate=[Basic realm="Spring"]}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /v0/public/authentication/password
       Parameters = {pass=[password], user=[xenoterracide@gmail.com]}
          Headers = {}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = Full authentication is required to access this resource
          Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY], Strict-Transport-Security=[max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains], WWW-Authenticate=[Basic realm="Spring"]}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []


Wanted but not invoked:
jsonAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(
    <any>,
    <any>,
    <any>
);
-> at com.xenoterracide.rpf.sec.authn.AuthenticationTest.unsupportedMediaType(AuthenticationTest.java:76)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
jsonAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(
    <any>,
    <any>,
    <any>
);
-> at com.xenoterracide.rpf.sec.authn.AuthenticationTest.unsupportedMediaType(AuthenticationTest.java:76)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

    at com.xenoterracide.rpf.sec.authn.AuthenticationTest.unsupportedMediaType(AuthenticationTest.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
```

what do I need to do to have my test context calling the filter?

Comment: I would assume that your request matcher is not matching. I guess you can easily debug to check that. You didn't really say what the `ContentTypeContentNegotiationStrategy` is doing. Maybe look there?

Comment: @DaveSyer line 199 of  `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter` calls `if (!requiresAuthentication(request, response)) {` which is what actually calls the `MATCHER` in my code, but `doFilter` is never called so it would never hit that code. added that class though, just in case

Comment: That looks kosher then. You might have to create a self-contained sample to get to the bottom of this. It works for me, basically, with the pieces we know about so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the appropriate `WebSecurityAdapter` configuration

```
@TestConfiguration
static class Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers( JsonAuthenticationFilter.AUTH_PASS ).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could have changed the order of your filter so it comes before the Spring Security one.

Comment: @DaveSyer I wish that both `@Order` and "authorizeRequests" required less centralized management. Couldn't I just annotate a controller/method `@Authorize( ALL )` and it would figure reflectively figure out the mvc routes? problem with Order is it requires you to remember an integer order, instead of a relative "sequence" like an init system does (`@Order( BEFORE, SpringSecurityFilter.class)`. but yes, although in my original config I placed in in the at the same spot as the UserNamePasswordFilter.